Faulty Node Setup
I'm currently part the way to isolating the windows in this building by color range/threshold. I'm happy to keep the emissive areas as is, but have been unsuccessful in making the black areas invisible, to bring back to the original original texture.
Node Setup Attached Below.


You need to connect something to the "fac" of the mix shader

Yeah use mix shader to mix your normal shader with transparent shader and in fac input plug in your black and white mask you just made. The black areas will use one mix shader input and the white areas will use the other.
